# How many Draco engines does Dragon 2/Crew Dragon possess?

Tags: spacex, dragon, draco, engines

I *believe* Dragon 2 has the same number of [400N Draco thrusters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Draco_%28rocket_engine_family%29) that Dragon 1 has, [which is 18](http://www.spacex.com/news/2013/04/04/draco-thrusters), but I have not seen any confirmation of this.

Dragon 1 appears to have them arranged in 2 sets of 4, and 2 sets of 5, as seen in this photo:

[image]

Yet Dragon 2's layout is a bit different, if everything is symmetrical, it appears to have 4 sets of 3, and the 4 lone thrusters on the inside of the SuperDraco mold lines:

[image]

[image]

This produces a sum total of **16** Dracos. **So, what's right? Additionally, if there is a difference, why?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Going through my photos of the Dragon 2s we've seen so far (initial presentations - I've got photos from all angles of that one, and the pad abort test) you're right: the Dragon 2 has 16 Dracos.

According to a [thread on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/spacex/comments/2vvgkz/detailed_images_underneath_cots_2_dragon/?), Dragon 1 had two extra thrusters pointing 'up' because the 'up' thrusters are used for the reentry burn and SpaceX wanted more redundancy for those.
Presumably on Dragon 2, with 8 SuperDracos, redundancy for the reentry burn is taken care of.
All engines in one thruster group [are fed from one propellant tank](http://innerspace.net/spacex/failure-is-still-not-an-option-spacex-restores-dragon-systems/).